# How do I change the way time is displayed in OpenOffice?

Tags: windows-10, openoffice-writer

Currently, in OpenOffice writer, whenever I type in a time in a table, it adds extra zeros. For instance, 4:00pm becomes 04:00:00 PM.  How do I change that so that it appears just how I originally typed it? I’m using an HP 15 Notebook PC with Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I change that so that it appears just how I originally typed it?

Unfortunately `4:00pm` is not one of the built-in time formats.

If you want this to be to be displayed exactly as you typed it you need to choose `Text` for the formatting.

If you are happy to display `4:00PM` (note the capital PM) you need to use `H:MMAM/PM` for the format code.

1. Select the cells to format
2. Right-click and select "Number Format" from the pop-up menu.
3. The Number Format dialog box opens for you to set options for various categories of numerical data.

   - Set "Category" to "Text" to display `4:00pm` and press "OK"

   [image]

   - Set "Categary" to "Time" to display `4:00PM`, set "Format code" to "H:MMAM/PM" and press "OK"

   [image]

Note:

- Tested in LibreOffice Writer. The instructions for OpenOffice Writer should be the same.